# redux useSelector is not giving root state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on a project that use **Redux toolkit** in **typescript** language.
The problem is that when I use `createSelector` it returns **wrong state object** in some of the selectors, **not all of them**. And it will work, if I use `store.getState()` instead of  returned state. Let me describe more details.

---

My state includes one reducer which includes two reducers that combined using `combineReducers`, as shows below.

```
const entities = combineReducers({
    trello: entityTrello,
    users: entityUser,
})

export function makeStore() {
    return configureStore({
        reducer: {
            entities: entities,
        },
        devTools: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_STATUS == "develop",
    })
}
```

> `trello reducer` contains **boards** and **their cards**.

> `users reducer` contains **list of users**.

---

all things go right and after saving data in store I got below state tree

[image]

---

Then I try to get data from state using `createSelector`.

```
export const selectLanesByBoardId = () => {
    return useAppSelector<BoardData>(selector => createSelector(
        (state: AppState) => state.entities.trello.tables.data?.boards,
        (state: AppState) => state.entities.trello.tables.data?.lanes,
        (state: AppState) => state.entities.trello.tables.data?.cards,
        (state: AppState) => state.entities.trello.meta.boardId,
        (state: AppState) => state.entities.trello.meta.workspace,
        (boards, lists, cards, boardId, workspace) => {
            let data: Array<Lane>
            // because we have key-value array, first we change it to simple array using "objectValues"
            // then find lanes of current board by "boardId" which sent from component (it's ids of lanes, not whole object)
            const laneIds = objectValues<TrelloBoard>(boards)?.find(value => value.id == boardId)?.lists
            // now with using "laneIds" search for specific lane objects
            const lanes = objectValues<TrelloLanes>(lists)?.filter(value => laneIds?.includes(value.id))
            // any lane has it's own cards that not implemented yet, so update cards field using "map" on array of lanes
            data = lanes.map(lane => ({
                ...lane,
                cards: objectValues<TrelloCard>(cards)
                    ?.filter(value => lane?.cards?.includes(value.id))
                    .map(value => ({
                        ...value,
                        draggable: workspace == "free",
                        laneId: lane.id
                    }))
            }))

            return {lanes: data} as BoardData
        }
    )(selector))
}
```

It goes right again, and I got correct data.

---

But in another `createSelector` the returned state is not the root state. please check below code.

```
export const selectUsers = () => {
    return useAppSelector<Array<User>>(selector => createSelector(
        (state: AppState) => {
            return state.entities.users.tables.data?.users
        },
        (users) => {
            return users ?? []
        }
    )(selector))
}
```

In this part of code I get an error which shows below.
[image]

---

As I said, it will work if I use `store.getState()` instead of `state`. Here is the code

```
export const selectUsers = () => {
    return useAppSelector<Array<User>>(selector => createSelector(
        (state: AppState) => {
            return store.getState().entities.users.tables.data?.users
        },
        (users) => {
            return users ?? []
        }
    )(selector))
}
```

Last, my question is why `createSelector` is not returning the root state in some part of the code, but `store.getState()` does. Any help, please?

---

**update**

As the shared image of the error shows, it says that entities object is undefined, **not users**. So I figured out that the root state is changing as @GabrielePetrioli noted in a comment, by adding a new `console.log` in `createSelector` of users, the state shows below data in the console log.
[image]

it's showing a new object instead of my store structure.
But how may the root state entity changes? I even has no access to entities object in my reducers.
below code is one of updating samples of the state.

```
        state.tables.data && (state.tables.data = {
            ...state.tables.data,
            lanes: state.utils.nextStateAfterLastAction?.lanes ?? [],
            cards: state.utils.nextStateAfterLastAction?.cards ?? [],
        })
```

as you can see, I just have access to the tables object, not the entities object.
every reducer updates its own state, not the root structure of the state!

Comment: Could it be that somewhere you are setting the state in way that overwrites it (*instead of updating the relevant part only*) and loses the `users` property ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli But I shared an image of the tree state in the question, everything shows ok. `users array` is exist!

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I just updated the post with new information. would you please check the updated part?

Comment: Unrelated probably, but I don't think `createSelector` is meant to be used that way. You're re-creating a memoized selector every time the hook gets called, this is not necessary.

Comment: @timotgl thanks for your answer. Do you mean `createSelector` is not necessary to get users from the store? and I should use `useSelector` instead?

Comment: I meant that `createSelector` only needs to be called *once* when your app loads. After that, the memoized selector exists and can be called. In your code whenever a component uses `selectUsers` for example, `createSelector` is called again. You could move the selector creation outside of the hook to avoid that. The correct usage is shown here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors